# laravel 5.2 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is very common question on stack overflow.I tried few of them but those not work for my scenario.
I try to pass edit data set to database but i got a error like
**NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161** 
In **edit.blade.php** i pass **PUT** method but check Inspect then their has show **Request Method:GET**.Please help me

***edit.blade.php***

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="PUT" action="{{ URL::to('phonebook/update/$data->id') }}" >
        <input type="text" hidden name="id" value="{{$data->id}}"/>
        <input type="text" name="phoneNo" value="{{$data->phoneNo}}"/>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="{{$data->email}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>

</body>
```

***PhonebookController.php***

```
  public function edit($id)
{
    $data = Phonebooks::find($id);
    return view('phonebook.edit', compact('data'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   echo"test";
}
```

***routes.php***

```
Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
Route::post('phonebook', 'PhonebookController@store');
Route::resource('phonebook', 'PhonebookController');

Route::put('phonebook/update','PhonebookController@update');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form to

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('phoneUpdate', $data->id ) }}" >
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="phoneNo" value="{{$data->phoneNo}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="{{$data->email}}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
</body>
```

your route to

```
Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
Route::post('phonebook', 'PhonebookController@store');
Route::resource('phonebook', 'PhonebookController');

Route::put('phonebook/update/{$id}','PhonebookController@update')->name('phoneUpdate');
```

More about [NAMED ROUTES](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes)

**UPDATE:**
Or, since you are using RESOURCE controller, you don't even need to specify that `PUT` route. Resource controller alreday provides you a `PUT` route with

```
path - phonebook/{$id}
route name - phonebook.update
```

So you could also change your form like this

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('phonebook.update', $data->id ) }}" >
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="phoneNo" value="{{$data->phoneNo}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="{{$data->email}}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
</body>
```

and remove that `put` from route like this :

```
Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
Route::post('phonebook', 'PhonebookController@store');
Route::resource('phonebook', 'PhonebookController');
```

More about [RESOURCE CONTROLLERS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

Since HTML forms only support POST & GET methods, PUT and DELETE methods should be spoofed by adding a _method hidden field to your form like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('phonebook/update/$data->id') }}" >
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
        <input `enter code here`type="text" hidden name="id" value="{{$data->id}}"/>
        <input type="text" name="phoneNo" value="{{$data->phoneNo}}"/>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="{{$data->email}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>

</body>
```

also your routes.php file don't seem to have entry for **/phonebook/update/{{ID}}**

`Route::put('phonebook/update/{id}','PhonebookController@update');`

should do

Comment: check update. your routes.php file also needs change.

Comment: Thank You so much for helping me. After change <form method="POST" action="{{ route('phonebook.update', $data->id ) }}" > then it's work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use form method as `POST` as you have specified PUT in hidden input field.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('phonebook/update/$data->id') }}" >
```

Comment: Thank You so much for helping me. After change <form method="POST" action="{{ route('phonebook.update', $data->id ) }}" > then it's work